# Klaviyo is unable to connect to Magento Server for OAuth Handshake

Tags: oauth, magento2

Quoting this answer: https://community.klaviyo.com/integrations-39/magento-2-4-1-integration-issue-2147?postid=7443#post7443

I have a question to **"how to solve that?"**

Because I am also facing a similar issue while integrating.

**==ERROR MESSAGE==**

We ran into an error
There was an error while integrating your Klaviyo account with Magento 2. Below are the details about your error

Klaviyo is unable to connect to Magento Server for OAuth Handshake.

Url tried was: None

Please ensure that both /oauth/token/request and /oauth/token/access
are accessible

So if you can help me, it will be very much useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was no issues in the code or the module.
The problem was, I was using magento in localhost, so klaviyo was not able to connect it.
I moved to a public IP and removed the sub folder format in url, i.e., localhost/magento2 was my url. Changed it to work with localhost/

So now klaviyo is working.

Answer (score 0):

Getting same above issue on Magento 2.4.2 with Klaviyo Integration.

Solution:

> /vendor/magento/module-integration/Controller/Adminhtml/Integration/TokensExchange.php
>
> use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
>
> class TokensExchange extends Integration implements
> HttpPostActionInterface,HttpGetActionInterface
>
> Added additional interface HttpGetActionInterface

Please override this file to local

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/68d20230ca9d6198fa3093eb174e24aff47b1646#comments